MOVE DB before restore, syntax error
I'm ready to pull my hair out. I made a script to backup and restore DB and Filegroup that build query like :
RESTORE DATABASE [dashdb_dev01_2024-04-11 143711] FROM DISK = 'E:\SQL2019_Data\Backup\dev01\20240410\1437\dashdb_dev01_2024-04-11 143711.bak' WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY, MOVE [dashdb_dev01_2024-04-11 143711] TO 'E:\SQL2019_Data\Backup\OLD\dashdb_dev01_2024-04-11 143711.mdf'

And I got :

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server FRPARPLMA-DBDEV, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'dashdb_dev01_2024-04-11 143711'.


I use [...] to escape db name, but I understand from the MSG 102 that's the 102th char (I'm right here ?). So it's the 'E:\SQL2019_Data\Backup\dev01\20240410\1437\dashdb_dev01_2024-04-11 143711.bak' after the FROM DISK.
How can I escape, I think, the space here?

If you format your command over multiple lines then you will get a more specific error message.
Restore Command
RESTORE DATABASE [dashdb_dev01_2024-04-11 143711] 
    FROM DISK = 'E:\SQL2019_Data\Backup\dev01\20240410\1437\dashdb_dev01_2024-04-11 143711.bak' 
    WITH REPLACE, 
        RECOVERY, 
        MOVE [dashdb_dev01_2024-04-11 143711] 
        TO 'E:\SQL2019_Data\Backup\OLD\dashdb_dev01_2024-04-11 143711.mdf'

Error Message

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 <------ HERE THE MORE SPECIFIC LINE NUMBER
Incorrect syntax near 'dashdb_dev01_2024-04-11 143711'.

Completion time: 2024-04-18T11:26:04.3459668+02:00


SQL Server Management Studio
If you look at the statement in SSMS then you will notice a red underlined part:

This is where the error is occuring.
Solution
The syntax for the RESTORE ... command is well documented at RESTORE Statements (Transact-SQL) and the solution is to use single quotes ' for the logical name according to this section of the documentation:
<general_WITH_options> [ ,...n ]::=
--Restore Operation Options
   MOVE 'logical_file_name_in_backup' TO 'operating_system_file_name'
          [ ,...n ]

So your script would look like this:
RESTORE DATABASE [dashdb_dev01_2024-04-11 143711] 
    FROM DISK = 'E:\SQL2019_Data\Backup\dev01\20240410\1437\dashdb_dev01_2024-04-11 143711.bak' 
    WITH REPLACE, 
        RECOVERY, 
        MOVE 'dashdb_dev01_2024-04-11 143711' TO 'E:\SQL2019_Data\Backup\OLD\dashdb_dev01_2024-04-11 143711.mdf';

